# what the best way to insert a relationship table in mysql using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

First of all I have to say I'm totally newbi in NodeJS technologies. 
But, I've tried to do something to try to learn it.

This is the problem: 
I have 3 tables (PARTICIPANT, ADDRESS_PARTICIPANT and INSCRIPTION).

The ADDRESS_PARTICIPANT contains participant_id (it's the participant's address).

The INSCRIPTION contains participant_id

So, to store a inscription row, at first I need to save the PARTICIPANT and the ADDRESS_PARTICIPANT. Only after this I could insert INSCRIPTION

I'm doing this in the way i've learn, but I think there are a lot of nested ifs.

How could I improve this code? Someone told me with Promise i'll well.. but I don't know. Someone could help me? Thanks

Here is the code:

```
this.save = function(data, retur) {
var con = db();
const SQL_INSERT_PARTICIPANT = 
  `INSERT INTO participant (nome_completo, tipo_funcionario, data_nascimento, sexo, unidade, cpf, email, telefone, telefone_emergencia) VALUES( ? )` ; 
const SQL_INSERT_ADDRESS_PARTICIPANT = 
  `INSERT INTO endereco_participante (participant_id, cep, estado, cidade, bairro, endereco, numero) values( ? )`;

const SQL_INSERT_INSCRIPTIONS = `......` 

var values = [
  data.nome_completo, data.tipo_funcionario, new Date(dateToEN(data.data_nascimento)), data.sexo, data.unidade, data.cpf_funcionario, data.email, data.telefone, data.telefone_emergencia
]

const insertParticipante = con.query(SQL_INSERT_PARTICIPANT , [values], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var values_end = [
    result.insertId, data.cep, data.estado, data.cidade, data.bairro, data.endereco, data.numero
  ]

  if (result.affectedRows > 0 ) {
    const insertEndPart = con.query(SQL_INSERT_ADDRESS_PARTICIPANT , [values_end], function(err, result2 ) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('Number of records inserted in ADDRESS_PARTICIPANT table: ' + result2.affectedRows);
      console.log('insertId.: ' + result2.insertId)

      if (result.affectedRows > 0 ) {
        const insertInscricao = con.query(SQL_INSERT_INSCRIPTIONS, [values_ins], function(err, result3) {
          console.log(`Inscription recorded! id: `+resul3.insertId)
        })

      }
    })
  }          
})
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID` i assume every table has a primray key column with a auto_increment option.

> With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit)
>   value representing the first automatically generated value
>   successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the
>   most recently executed INSERT statement. The value of LAST_INSERT_ID()
>   remains unchanged if no rows are successfully inserted.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Then you can use these `INSERT`'s in NodeJS instead.

```
INSERT INTO participant (nome_completo, tipo_funcionario, data_nascimento, sexo, unidade, cpf, email, telefone, telefone_emergencia) VALUES( <other columns> )
```

This insert below will use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the participant.id

```
INSERT INTO endereco_participante (participant_id, cep, estado, cidade, bairro, endereco, numero) values( LAST_INSERT_ID(), <other columns> )
```

With three table the problem gets more complex. 
Then you can use MySQL's user variables.

```
INSERT INTO participant (nome_completo, tipo_funcionario, data_nascimento, sexo, unidade, cpf, email, telefone, telefone_emergencia) VALUES( <other columns> )

SET @participant_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO endereco_participante (participant_id, cep, estado, cidade, bairro, endereco, numero) values( @participant_id, <other columns> )

SET @endereco_participante_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Then you can use @participant_id and @endereco_participante_id in the third insert query. (which seams you didn't provided in your question). 
Note the SET queries are separated queries so you need to execute them also with `con.query('SET @participant_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();', ..)`